# Convert System.Windows.Media.ImageSource to System.Drawing.Bitmap

Tags: c#, wpf, image

How can I convert a System.Windows.Media.ImageSource to a System.Drawing.Bitmap in C#?

Answer (score 16):

its older OP, but still it can come handy for some other people, as it took some time to find cleaner solution without dll interop or clipboard hacks.

this worked for me, you can use pngencoder to cut the image size before saving to file or rtf stream

```
private System.Drawing.Image ImageWpfToGDI(System.Windows.Media.ImageSource image) {
  MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
  var encoder = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BmpBitmapEncoder();
  encoder.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(image as System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource));
  encoder.Save(ms);
  ms.Flush();      
  return System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
}
```

Comment: If you need to convert images with alpha channel (with transparent parts), use System.Windows.Media.Imaging.PngBitmapEncoder() instead of System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BmpBitmapEncoder().

Comment: @DariuszWasacz I can't get this answer to work. It complains that image.Source does not work: **'System.Drawing.Image' does not contain a definition for 'Source' and no extension method 'Source' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Drawing.Image' could be found.**

I checked MSDN and Image does not have a Source property. Do you have any idea what needs to be fixed?

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck: Please note that both System.Drawing and System.Windows.Media namespaces contain class 'Image'. It looks like that you omitted namespace in argument 'System.Windows.Media.Image image' and 'System.Drawing.Image' was taken from using statements. Please check if your code is exactly the same as above.

Comment: I feel like I'm missing something here, @DariuszWasacz. You were right in that it was using System.Drawing.Image, so kudos for that, but I can't find a member of System.Windows.Media that is "Image". The closest I can find is System.Windows.Media.ImageSource. Since your code above used the .Source attribute of Image, it seemed like the logical leap.

Comment: @kayleeFrye_onDeck: The code above wasn't originally mine :-). My code goes like this:

      public static System.Drawing.Image ImageWpfToGdi2(this ImageSource image)

      {

         var ms = new MemoryStream();

         var encoder = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.PngBitmapEncoder();
         encoder.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create((System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource)image));

         encoder.Save(ms);
         ms.Flush();
         var btm = (System.Drawing.Bitmap)System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms);
         return btm;
      }

Answer (score 0):

Please see [HOW TO USE IMAGESOURCE (NO HANDLER) IN WINFORMS AS SYSTEM.DRAWING.BITMAP (HBITMAP)](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/tamir/archive/2007/09/09/How-to-use-ImageSource-_2800_no-handler_2900_-in-WinForms-as-System.Drawing.Bitmap-_2800_hbitmap_2900_.aspx):

> How to easily convert WinForms
>   System.Drawing.Bitmap into WPF
>   ImageSource you learned from this
>   article. Today, I'll explain how to do
>   it contrary. Actually, all he have to
>   do is to extract handler from
>   BitmapSource, however, such approach
>   is not supported, thus the only thing
>   we can do is just copy pixels of
>   BitmapSource (or BitmapFrame) into
>   byte array and then copy them into the
>   pointer of HBitmap.

Comment: Both this and previous posts are the same approach: copy bitmap scan lines to a byte array and then create a bitmap from memory block. The bitmap assumes that the memory block contains scan lines during the bitmap lifetime. However after leaving the fixed(byte* pB = bits) code, the memory can be overwritten by .net memory manager and the bitmap gets corrupted. The solution is to use Marshal.AllocHGlobal, but in this case the memory block must be be maintained by user code (that is: must be freed after use by Marshal.FreeHGlobal).

Comment: Link is dead; this is why we ask people to post answers instead of links.