# how to "convert a system.windows.control.image" to "System.Drawing.Image" in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

Hello friends i want to "convert a system.windows.control.image" to "System.Drawing.Image",but i am unable to do so.I am using below code for this

```
var e = (MouseButtonEventArgs)sender;
var device = e.MouseDevice.DirectlyOver;
System.Windows.Controls.Image img = (System.Windows.Controls.Image)device;
```

I have "img" i.e of type "system.windows.control.image" i need to convert it to bitmap or drawing type.

Comment: bitmap image=img.Image;

Comment: @Dexter img dont have property of image type,because of type windows.controls.image

Comment: Why do you want a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`?  Most everything except interop with old code can be done without conversion.

Comment: I just want to convert it in to system.drawing.image @Mitch

Comment: Assuming you are referring to the image displayed (the `Source` property), that would be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1201518/convert-system-windows-media-imagesource-to-system-drawing-bitmap, but you could also call `CopyPixels` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapsource.copypixels(v=vs.110).aspx) and pass the result to GDI as raw pixel data.

Comment: I am little confused with the posted code snippet. is it just a guess work or is it what you intend to do?

Answer (score 2):

Try this....

Use your img variable in this code...

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(); 
System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BmpBitmapEncoder bbe = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
bbe.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(new Uri(img.Source.ToString(),UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute)));

bbe.Save(ms); 
System.Drawing.Image img2 = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms); 
button1.Image = img2;
```

**convert from byte[] to image**

```
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageByte);
    Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
```

it may help you..

Comment: Agarwal  we dont have source of image we are taking images stored in database i.e in the form of bytes
actually i am taking images from database that are binded to listbox,when i click on any image i need bytes of that image.So Uri king will generate error in your case

Comment: Agarwal from where i got "imageByte" that i dont have with me i have image buffer,so how could i read image buffer now?

Comment: Are you getting image path or something ?

Comment: no image path no bytes,direct image that is initially binded from database using bytes and now want to read same bytes